# Error as NSFetchedResultsController populates and changes UITableView Rows and Sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Let me first say this is my first time posting on Stack Overflow and this is my first iOS application.

#### The App

My friends and I like to play [Carcassonne](https://carcassonneapp.com).  We decided to start an ongoing league to keep track of wins & scores.  This app tracks those games and shares the results in our group chat.

#### The Data

I am using CoreData to store three entities: Season, Game and Player.  Here are their attributes / relationships:
[screenshot of xcdatamodel graph view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk6PU.png)

#### The ViewControllers

I followed [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html) for connecting NSFetchedResultsController to a UITableView.  My UITableViewControllers are wrapped in a Navigation Controller.  Snippets of my code is below.

#### The Goal

Be able to toggle players' between the Playing and Bench sections after navigating away in the Navigation Controller (in case I need to make an edit after showing the scorebaord).

#### Results

**Expected**: Tapping a player name should toggle their isPlaying attribute and move them between the two sections of the UITableView.

**Actual**: Tapping a player name after navigating away and coming back to the UITableView crashes the application.

#### The Error

[Here is a video of the error.](https://share.icloud.com/photos/08PNrjMVCzZ4rkdn0dLZU3b5A)

I have the tableView's didSelectRowAt toggle the Player's isPlaying boolean attribute.  isPlaying will determine which section of the UITableView that Player's row will live.  When I create a new game, I can move players from the bench section (isPlaying = false) back and forth to the playing section (isPlaying = true) just fine.  However, when I navigate away from this view (to my standings page, for example) and back to it in the Navigation Controller, the app crashes when I try to select a row again.

```
2020-08-28 11:53:04.354939-0400 FetchTest[5427:86101] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3920.31.102/UITableView.m:2108
2020-08-28 11:53:04.355249-0400 FetchTest[5427:86101] [error] fault: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to delete row 4 from section 0 which only contains 4 rows before the update with userInfo (null)
CoreData: fault: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to delete row 4 from section 0 which only contains 4 rows before the update with userInfo (null)
2020-08-28 11:53:04.355397-0400 FetchTest[5427:86101] [error] CoreData: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to delete row 4 from section 0 which only contains 4 rows before the update with userInfo (null)
2020-08-28 11:53:04.357387-0400 FetchTest[5427:86101] [error] error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  attempt to delete row 4 from section 0 which only contains 4 rows before the update with userInfo (null)
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  attempt to delete row 4 from section 0 which only contains 4 rows before the update with userInfo (null)
2020-08-28 11:53:04.361285-0400 FetchTest[5427:86101] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 4 from section 0 which only contains 4 rows before the update'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3de6e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff512539b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3dbe8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff258d6bd2 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4950188a -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 6824
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4951dace -[UITableView endUpdatesWithContext:] + 112
    6   FetchTest                           0x0000000109df538f $s9FetchTest29GameDetailTableViewControllerC26controllerDidChangeContentyySo016NSFetchedResultsG0CySo20NSFetchRequestResult_pGF + 287
    7   FetchTest                           0x0000000109df53f4 $s9FetchTest29GameDetailTableViewControllerC26controllerDidChangeContentyySo016NSFetchedResultsG0CySo20NSFetchRequestResult_pGFTo + 68
    8   CoreData                            0x00007fff23b7d69d __82-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:]_block_invoke + 7591
    9   CoreData                            0x00007fff23a0338d developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 154
    10  CoreData                            0x00007fff23a03274 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 197
    11  CoreData                            0x00007fff23b7b8e4 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 105
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d68d2c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d681a5 _CFXRegistrationPost1 + 421
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d67f11 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 193
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e65473 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1795
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d67866 _CFXNotificationPost + 950
    17  Foundation                          0x00007fff2593826b -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 59
    18  CoreData                            0x00007fff239efaa2 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 541
    19  CoreData                            0x00007fff23a9380f -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:deletions:updates:refreshes:deferrals:wasMerge:] + 1557
    20  CoreData                            0x00007fff239ea599 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 1217
    21  CoreData                            0x00007fff239ed8ff -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 367
    22  FetchTest                           0x0000000109df0b33 $s9FetchTest29GameDetailTableViewControllerC9saveGamesyyF + 131
    23  FetchTest                           0x0000000109df02c7 $s9FetchTest29GameDetailTableViewControllerC05tableF0_14didSelectRowAtySo07UITableF0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtF + 1543
    24  FetchTest                           0x0000000109df0427 $s9FetchTest29GameDetailTableViewControllerC05tableF0_14didSelectRowAtySo07UITableF0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtFTo + 167
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff495212de -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:isCellMultiSelect:] + 1354
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49520d7d -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 97
    27  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff495216be -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 334
    28  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4932eb76 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 352
    29  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4931f304 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 248
    30  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4934fb0d _afterCACommitHandler + 85
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da1087 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9bb3e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9c08a __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9b8a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
    35  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38c39bbe GSEventRunModal + 139
    36  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49325968 UIApplicationMain + 1605
    37  FetchTest                           0x0000000109de0ceb main + 75
    38  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff520ce1fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

#### The Code

I have:

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>!
```

in the class and

```
initializeFetchedResultsController()
```

is called in viewDidLoad().

Here are my UITableView Methods from my GameDetailTableViewController:

```
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController.sections!.count
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections else {
            fatalError("No sections in fetchedResultsController")
        }
        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
        
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections else {
            fatalError("No sections in fetchedResultsController")
        }
        if sections[section].indexTitle == "0" {
            return "Bench"
        } else {
            return "Playing"
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "gameDetailCell", for: indexPath) as! PlayerCell
        
        guard let object = self.fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath) as? Player else {
            fatalError("Attempt to configure cell without a managed object")
        }
        
        cell.player = object
        
        cell.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
        
        //Set Name and Image
        
        if let name = object.name {
            cell.playerCellLabel.text = "\(name)"
            cell.playerImageView.image = maskRoundedImage(image: UIImage(named: name)!, radius: 15)
        }
        
        cell.playerScoreTextField.text = String(object.score)
        cell.playerScoreTextField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true
        cell.playerScoreTextField.delegate = self
        
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        guard let object = self.fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath) as? Player else {
            fatalError("Attempt to configure cell without a managed object")
        }
        
        print("Row \(indexPath.row) in section \(indexPath.section) was tapped.")
        
        
        object.isPlaying = !object.isPlaying
        saveGames()
 
    }
```

Here's my NSFetchedResultsController Extension.  This was based off the Apple guide linked above.  (Yes, it's not very DRY with the initializeStandingsFetchedResultsController(), that's next on my list.)  I'm using my isPlaying boolean attribute as the sectionNameKeyPath.

```
extension GameDetailTableViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    // MARK: - NSFetchedResultsController
    func initializeFetchedResultsController() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Player")
        let isPlayingSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "isPlaying", ascending: false)
        let scoreSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "score", ascending: false)
        request.sortDescriptors = [isPlayingSort, scoreSort]
        
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: K.context, sectionNameKeyPath: "isPlaying", cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        
        fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "game.dateCreated == %@", selectedGame!.dateCreated! as CVarArg)
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
            
            playerArray = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as! [Player]
            
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func initializeStandingsFetchedResultsController() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Player")
        let scoreSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "score", ascending: false)
        request.sortDescriptors = [scoreSort]
        
        standingsFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: K.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        standingsFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        
        standingsFetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "game.dateCreated == %@", selectedGame!.dateCreated! as CVarArg)
        do {
            try standingsFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
            
            
            standingsPlayerArray = standingsFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as! [NSManagedObject]
            
            
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate Methods
    
    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }
    
    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
        case .delete:
            tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
        case .move:
            break
        case .update:
            break
        @unknown default:
            fatalError("You did something funky with the table view.")
        }
    }
    
    
    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
        case .delete:
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
        case .update:
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
        case .move:
            tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
        @unknown default:
            fatalError("You did something funky with the table view.")
        }
    }
    
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}</pre>

saveGames() is just this:
<pre>func saveGames() {
        do {
            try K.context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error saving games. \(error)")
        }
    }</pre>
And my K.context is:
<pre>struct K {
    static let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
}
```

As I mentioned above, this is my first post and first app.  I'm a self taught programmer just learning iOS and Swift, so please go easy on me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My controller didChange anObject (in the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate Methods section) was firing the .move followed by .update for the same indexPath.  Once the .move fired, there was no longer an object at that indexPath so the .update failed.

This is why it only failed when tapping on the last row in the video.  For my code, I'm not using the .update, so I just commented it out.